# Windows 2008 x64 - WCF IIS - OracleException ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: wcf, oracle, iis, windows-server-2008, ora-12154

I have **WCF** service is hosted in **IIS** on a **Windows 2008 x64** machine. This WCF service needs to access an Oracle database but when it tries to do so it encounters an OracleException with the following error message:

**ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified**

I tried to test the connection to the Oracle database using a Universal Data Link (UDL) file and that works fine. May I assume that the Oracle client is correctly installed on my Windows 2009 server ? If so, what else could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a TNSPING to your oracle server, that will tell you if the connection can be established.

Also check if you have multiple Oracle Clients installed on that machine.

Comment: Especially if you might have 32bit and 64 bit clients.

Answer (score 0):

Check your [tnsnames file](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora).  More description of [that error here](http://ora-12154.ora-code.com/).